# How to: Get a Python Scrapy to run a simple xpath retrieval

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm very new to python and am trying to build a script that will eventually extract page titles and s from specified URLs to a .csv in the format I specify.

I have tried managed to get the spider to work in CMD using :

```
response.xpath("/html/head/title/text()").get()
```

So the xpath must be right.

Unfortunately when I run the the file my spider is in it never seems to work properly. I think the issue is in the final block of code, unfortunately all the guides I follow seem to use CSS.  I feel more comfortable with xpath because you can simply copy,paste it from Dev Tools.

```
import scrapy
class PageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dorothy"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com/blog"]

def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.xpath("/html/head/title/text()"):
        yield {
        "title": sel.xpath("Title a::text").extract_first()
        }
```

I expected when that to give me the page title of the above URLs.

Comment: What is `sel` in your code? Are the indents of `parse` function ok and it is inside your class?

Comment: What is the error? Can you elaborate on how it does not "work properly"?

Comment: @vezunchik Thanks for pointing out the sel. - I just realised I haven't assigned sel to anything. I got pretty confused looking through lots of examples, and may have bundled them up.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your second url on `self.start_urls` is invalid and returning 404, so you will end up with only one title extracted.

Second, you need to read more about [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), you extracted the title on your test on shell but got confused when using it on your spider.

Scrapy will call the `parse` method for each url on `self.start_urls`, so you don't need to iterate trough titles, you only have one per page.

You also can access the `<title>` tag directly using `//` at the beginning of your xpath expression, see this text copied from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) :

```
/   Selects from the root node
//  Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
import scrapy

class PageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dorothy"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "title": response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        }
```

Comment: Yes! It works.  I'll have a look into selectors, although I'm struggling to understand terminology like callbacks, responses, etc.  I'm sure it's just because I'm new, hopefully they will stick soon. Thanks for the help, I'm looking forward to the next step in my project - extracting to a .csv

Comment: Read Scrapy tutorial carefully, change parts of code to better understand what everything means. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html At the beginning it sure is confusing but keep reading and coding and you will improve. Good luck!